# changing value of flask variable in html

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am making a web application with flask, I know for a fact that you can create variables in the python file to use in the HTML file in jinja, but how can I change the value of a variable inside the HTML?

Can I do it like this?
`{{ VAR_NAME == NEW_VAR_VALUE }}`

help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean like this https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#assignments or something else when you say in the HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a flask code like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def simple_page():
    random_number = random.randint(1, 6)

    return render_template('page.html', number=random_number)
```

Then you can access that variable through jinja2 like this:

```
<p>Random number: {{ number }}</p>
```

If you want to assign the variable passed from flask to another variable created in jinja2 (you wanna make a copy, I don't know) just write:

```
{% set new_var = number %}
```

Now you can use the variable `new_var` in the jinja2 code.

Wanna increase `new_var`? Do:

```
{% set new_var = new_var+1 %}
```

Comment: so you cant change the var that was passed from flask, but thanks you for the tips, will sure try :)